# C programming exercise?

Tags: c

I'm reading a book on C programming and try to do the exercises:

**Write a program that prints a horizontal histogram consisting of stars(*). One star for every number there can be in the interval 0 ... 70.**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void draw_stars(int number_of_stars) {
    int counter = 0;

    for(counter = 0; counter < number_of_stars; counter++) {
        printf("*");
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {

    int counter1, counter2, ones, tens, zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine = 0;

    for(tens = 0; tens < 7; tens++) {
         if(tens == 0)
             zero = zero + 1;
         if(tens == 1)
             one = one + 10;
         if(tens == 2)
             two = two + 10;
         if(tens == 3)
             three = three + 10;
         if(tens == 4)
             four = four + 10;
         if(tens == 5)
             five = five + 10;
         if(tens == 6)
             six = six + 10;
         if(tens == 7)
             seven = seven + 10;

             for(ones = 0; ones < 9; ones++) {
                 if(ones == 0)
                     zero++;
                 if(ones == 1)
                     one++;
                 if(ones == 2)
                     two++;
                 if(ones == 3)
                     three++;
                 if(ones == 4)
                     four++;
                 if(ones == 5)
                     five++;
                 if(ones == 6)
                     six++;
                 if(ones == 7)
                     seven++;
                 if(ones == 8)
                     eight++;
                 if(ones == 9)
                     nine++;
        }
    }

draw_stars(zero);
draw_stars(one);
draw_stars(two);
draw_stars(three);
draw_stars(four);
draw_stars(five);
draw_stars(six);
draw_stars(seven);
draw_stars(eight);
draw_stars(nine);

}
```

*For some reason my program enters a infinite loop printing stars. But I can't find out why?*

*I haven't been able to come up with any other solution, but I still think it's ugly and bloated. How would a real C programmer solve this?*

## Edit:

After reading and understanding the chapter about arrays in the book, I was able to write a more clean version of the program. I'm posting it here as it might help other beginners understand the use of arrays. Writing an identical program in terms of output, but using different functionality of the language is a great learning experience.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TENS 7

void draw_stars(int stars) {
    int star_counter = 0;

    for (star_counter = 0; star_counter < stars; star_counter++)
        printf("%c", '*');
}

int main(void) {

    int number_array[10];
    int tens_counter, ones_counter;

    for (ones_counter = 0; ones_counter < 10; ones_counter++)
        number_array[ones_counter] = 0;

    for (tens_counter = 0; tens_counter < TENS; tens_counter++) {
        if (tens_counter != 0)
            number_array[tens_counter] += 10;
        else
            number_array[tens_counter] += 1;

        for (ones_counter = 0; ones_counter < 10; ones_counter++)
            number_array[ones_counter]++;
    }

    for (ones_counter = 0; ones_counter < 10; ones_counter++) {
            draw_stars(number_array[ones_counter]);
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: only nine has being initialized.

Comment: As to how a _real_ C programmer would solve this: If you have come across an exercise with a histogram in your book, arrays have surely been explained already, haven't they?

Comment: Arrays are explained in the next chapter, so maybe after reading it I will be able to write a better version of the program.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I had somehow gotten the idea that all variables would be initialized to the value of the last one. I'm probably mistaken it with: `counter1 = counter2 = ones = tens = 0` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize all variables:

```
int counter1=0, counter2=0, ones=0, tens=0, zero=0, one=0..
```

BTW, for better performance,
replace `if` with `else if` except the first one in the block. Why do you want to check all `if` conditions when you already know only one is true?

FYI, when a condition is true in `Else if`, all other `if`s are skipped.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to initialize all ints to zero, you should write:

```
int counter1=0, counter2=0, ...
```

Now only `nine` is init by 0, other variables contain rubbish - arbitrary values.

Answer (score 1):

in main() you have to initialize all variable with zero like

```
  int counter1=0,counter2=0 and so on
```

otherwise it take garbage value and perform operation with those values and then output will be like

```
********
*****************
*****************
*****************
*****************
*****************
*****************
*******
*******
```